# Facebook app tab page shows nothing but a white canvas when not logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've setup a Facebook app and added it as a tab on my fanpage.

Being logged in as a user and requesting the direct URL for the app page, shows me everything correct.

HOWEVER, when I'm not logged in @facebook and I go to the direct URL then nothing is shown on the app page. It's simply displaying a white background on the canvas with a max height of 100px.

I can naturally login from that page and after callback from the login I see the app page normally again.

I figured it could have something to do with my code. But then I test deleted everything in my index.php file and only added some static dummy text. Still nothing shows up.

Any ideas?

EDIT 1:
I think this might have something to do with me redirecting all request for URL defined for the app canvas to https. I read somewhere else that it could be that Facebook also needs access to http of the same URL for some reason. But haven't found anything backing this up yet.

EDIT 2:
Seeing I couldn't even get anything up having a blank index.php with static text I'm not sure if this could be something with it. But turning on errors with my whole script on, I get some errors with $signed_request - guess because I'm calling it when not being able to retrieve it. Not sure what to do though, but posting the code anyway in case someone can see anything.

```
function parsePageSignedRequest() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
      $encoded_sig = null;
      $payload = null;
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
      $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
      $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
      return $data;
    }
    return false;
  }

if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {
    if($signed_request->page->liked) {
          //echo "This content is for Fans only!";
          $amFan = "true";
    } else {
          //echo "Please click on the Like button to view this tab!";
          $amFan = "false";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a signed_request when the user isn't logged in at all?

If not, your code is returning false in `parsePageSignedrequest()` and skipping the setting of `$amFan` entirely - does the rest of your code work in that case?